# Woocommerce shipping calculation timing out

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, woocommerce, hook

I've created a function `discount_foil_seal_items()` that applies a price change in the cart using the hook `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`.  It will update the cart totals fine but when I get to checkout the shipping calculation times out (ie spinning icon perpetually). I haven't been able to find any posts relating to this specific issue.

I tried commenting out sections of the function to see what was causing it and it seems that if I run either of the foreach in this function it times out.  Is it something to do with nesting an if statement or switch statement inside the foreach?

```
//apply discounts to foil and seal product categories
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'discount_foil_seal_items', 10, 1 );
function discount_foil_seal_items( $cart_object ) {

// Iterating through each item in cart
foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $item_values ) {

    // Get cart item data
    $item_id = $item_values['data']->id; // Product ID
    $item_qty = $item_values['quantity']; // Item quantity
    
    // Get the object
    $product = new WC_Product( $item_id );
    $prod_cat = wp_get_post_terms($product->id,'product_cat',array('fields'=>'slugs'));
    
    //tally totals
    if (in_array('seal-stickers', $prod_cat)){
        $seal_prod_tally += $item_qty;
    }else if(in_array('foil-badges', $prod_cat)){
        $foil_prod_tally += $item_qty;
    }
}

 foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $item_values ) {

    //Get cart item data
    $item_id = $item_values['data']->id; // Product ID
    $item_qty = $item_values['quantity']; // Item quantity

    // Get the object
    $product = new WC_Product( $item_id );
    $prod_cat2 = wp_get_post_terms($product->id,'product_cat',array('fields'=>'slugs'));        
    
    //apply discount to each item within category
    if (in_array('seal-stickers',$prod_cat2)){
        switch ($seal_prod_tally){
            case 25000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(1327.01/20000);
                echo 'case 25000 seal has run <br>';
                break;
            case 30000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(1578.65/30000);
                break;
            case 50000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(2126.76/50000);
                break;
            case 60000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(2405.98/60000);
                break;
        }        
    }else if (in_array( 'foil-badges',$prod_cat2)){
        switch ($foil_prod_tally){
            case 25000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(5872.63/25000);
                break;
            case 50000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(10815.47/50000);
                break;
        }            
    } 
    
 }
```

}

Also I've commented out both foreach and inserted a simplified foreach like below which runs fine:

```
//this foreach doesn't timeout
    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $item_values ){        
        $item_values['data']->set_price(1327.01/20000);
    }
```

Other products on this site checkout fine without timeout errors.

Any help on what is causing the timeout would be much appreciated!

Here's a screenshot of the timeout:

https://i.gyazo.com/f5869d0b7b01e4e73ff27885e5b18208.png

## Update

I tried rewriting the code replacing the switch statements with if else if blocks to no avail. I then tried splitting the functions into two separate ones just to see if that did anything which also didn't fix the timeout.  Here's the code split in two different functions:

```
//apply discounts to foil and seal product categories
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'cart_count_foil_seal_items',10,1);

function cart_count_foil_seal_items( $cart_object ) {
    echo 'discount_foil_seal_items() has run <br>';
    $seal_prod_tally = 0;
    $foil_prod_tally = 0;
// Iterating through each item in cart
foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $item_values ) {
    //  Get cart item data
    $item_id = $item_values['data']->get_id(); // Product ID
    $item_qty = $item_values['quantity']; // Item quantity
    
    // Getting the object
    $product = new WC_Product( $item_id );
    $prod_cat = wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(),'product_cat',array('fields'=>'slugs'));
    
    //tally total
    if (in_array('seal-stickers', $prod_cat)){
        $seal_prod_tally += $item_qty;
    }else if(in_array('foil-badges', $prod_cat)){
        $foil_prod_tally += $item_qty;
    }
}
 
 return array($seal_prod_tally,$foil_prod_tally);
}

//apply discounts to foil and seal product categories
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'discount_foil_seal_items',12);

function discount_foil_seal_items( $cart_object ) {
echo 'discount_foil_seal_items() has run <br>';

list($seal_prod_tally, $foil_prod_tally) = cart_count_foil_seal_items($cart_object);

 foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $item_values ) {

    //Get cart item data
    $item_id = $item_values['data']->get_id(); // Product ID
    $item_qty = $item_values['quantity']; // Item quantity

    // Getting the object
    $product = new WC_Product( $item_id );
    $prod_cat2 = wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(),'product_cat',array('fields'=>'slugs'));        
    
    //apply discount to each item within category

      if (in_array('seal-stickers',$prod_cat2)){

        switch ($seal_prod_tally){
            case 25000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(1327.01/20000);
                break;
            case 30000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(1578.65/30000);
                break;
            case 50000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(2126.76/50000);
                break;
            case 60000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(2405.98/60000);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }        
    }else if (in_array( 'foil-badges',$prod_cat2)){
        switch ($foil_prod_tally){
            case 25000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(5872.63/25000);
                break;
            case 50000:
                $item_values['data']->set_price(10815.47/50000);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }            
    }      
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue it was an echo statement that I had for debugging purposes. I removed that and it worked.  I didn't realize an echo statement would cause timeouts like that but it's good to know:

I removed this line:
`echo 'discount_foil_seal_items() has run <br>';`

In both functions and it works.